# Android AppUsageStatistics Sample

Tags: java, android

I tried to run this Android example:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics/#readme

but It doesn't work.
I have the three pre-requisites (Android SDK 27, Android Build Tools v27.0.2, Android Support Repository) and I changed the line code

```
mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getActivity()
       .getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
```

in AppUsageStatisticsFragment (as the #readme says).

I tried many ways to resolve this problem, but I don't managed to find a solution. 
I try to change the permission in Android Manifest from

`< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"/>`

to

```
< uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

but the code doesn't work.

Has anyone managed to make this Android example work?

Comment: did you get the permission at run time? and check whether you got permission

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Yes, I put in the Manifest the permission: " <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"/> " as the "read me" says. But the code doesn't work.

Comment: adding in manifest will not provide you a permission. You need to get UsageStat permission at run time

Comment: How can I go to insert a run time permission in the code if I can not build it? I can't open layouts, so I can not insert a permission a running time for this reason

Comment: go to settings and turn on Usage Access for your app , then launch your app. If it works, then the problem is permission. You can go to settings page and ask user to turn on permissions by code from your app, which I said "Run time permission"

Comment: The user can't see the app in settings, because the build doesn't work. I can't go to settings and turn on Usage Access for your app. I hope you understand me and I understand you correctly

Comment: I'm working with this library with the help of this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics code. 
It provides me with the last app used time. I want to get the app launched time. Is there any possibility of that. It was an urgent case. Thanks in adcance